# How to set equal size of cells in tabular environment?

Tags: tables

so i would like this table to have equal sized cells, but I cant seem to avoid the overlapping of cells in the second row. How can I define a size?

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{bm,array}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}CCCCCCC@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Gemeinn\"utzige Wohnungsunternehmen 1930 bis 1989}             \\ \midrule
                                                  & eG      & GmbH   & AG      & Sonstige & Insg.   & Wohnungsbestand \\
Reich 1988:                                       & 289     & \multicolumn{3}{l}{95}      & 384     &                 \\
Reich 1930:                                       & 2.596   & 222    & 56      & 43       & 2.917   & 555.400         \\
Reich 1939:                                       & 2.826   & 502    & 82      & 54       & 3.464   & 1.160.500       \\
Reich 1949:                                       & 1.676   & 369    & 74      & 31       & 2.150   & 840.000         \\
1949 zu 1939:                                     & - 41 \% & -26 \%\ & - 10 \%\ & - 43 \%\  & - 38 \%\ & - 28 \%\         \\
Bund 1939:                                        & 1.767   & 262    & 60      & 35       & 2.124   &                 \\
Bund 1950:                                        & 1.791   & 416    & 74      & 35       & 2.316   &                 \\
Bund 1960:                                        & 1.665   & 535    & 71      & 36       & 2.307   & 2.113.776       \\
Bund 1970:                                        & 1.406   & 573    & 64      & 34       & 2.077   & 2.926.699       \\
Bund 1980:                                        & 1.229   & 555    & 60      & 31       & 1.875   & 3.326.692       \\
Bund 1986:                                        & 1.193   & 542    & 59      & 32       & 1.826   & 3.387.593       \\
Bund 1991:                                        &         &        &         &          & 1.795   & 3.434.000       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Gemeinn\"utzige Wohnungsunternehmen 1930 bis 1991}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What on earth is svmono?

Comment: Maybe it defines `C` ?

Comment: svmono is a template for Springer Research books.
I defined C for a different table to get equal sized cells. Sorry for missing that part.

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2em}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equal width of cells you can determine with `p{<width>}` (or `m{<width>}` when vertical centering of cell's content is required) or with use of `tabularx` and its `X` type column.

In your case this doesn't mean, that the table will look fine. Contrary, since the natural columns widths very differ between them, the table will look strange. However, this is matter of taste ...

With `tabularx` and forced line breaks of last column head into two line, is possible to obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\small%tsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{6}{C}@{}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Gemeinn\"utzige Wohnungsunternehmen 1930 bis 1989}           \\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
            & eG    & GmbH   & AG     & Sonstige & Insg.   & Wohnungs\-bestand  \\
    \midrule
Reich 1988: & 289   & \multicolumn{3}{l}{95}     & 384     &                    \\
Reich 1930: & 2.596 & 222    & 56     & 43       & 2.917   & 555.400            \\
Reich 1939: & 2.826 & 502    & 82     & 54       & 3.464   & 1.160.500          \\
Reich 1949: & 1.676 & 369    & 74     & 31       & 2.150   & 840.000            \\
1949 zu 1939:   & - 41 \% 
                    & -26 \% & - 10 \%& -43 \%\  & - 38 \% & - 28 \%            \\
Bund 1939:  & 1.767 & 262    & 60     & 35       & 2.124   &                    \\
Bund 1950:  & 1.791 & 416    & 74     & 35       & 2.316   &                    \\
Bund 1960:  & 1.665 & 535    & 71     & 36       & 2.307   & 2.113.776          \\
Bund 1970:  & 1.406 & 573    & 64     & 34       & 2.077   & 2.926.699          \\
Bund 1980:  & 1.229 & 555    & 60     & 31       & 1.875   & 3.326.692          \\
Bund 1986:  & 1.193 & 542    & 59     & 32       & 1.826   & 3.387.593          \\
Bund 1991:  &       &        &        &          & 1.795   & 3.434.000          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Gemeinn\"utzige Wohnungsunternehmen 1930 bis 1991}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In code I omit all packages which not contribute to table formatting, and add `tabularx` and `geometry` package, and change `\usepackage{ngerman}` to `\usepackage[newgerman]{babel}` (what is probably more correct). I also not touch the text alignment in  `multicolumn` cells.